# Javascript / Typescript - Remove from object

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I remove all objects which contain `filter1`?

```
const obj = {
  0: {
    'filter1': {
      'key1': {
        'email1': 'email1'
      }
    }
  },
  1: {
    'filter1': {
      'key12': {
        'email12': 'email12'
      }
    }
  },
  2: {
    'filter2': {
      'key2': {
        'email2': 'email2'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your expected output? is it `{ 2: { filter2: { ... } } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get a new object:

```
const newObject = Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, key) => {
  if (!obj[key].filter1) {
    newObj[key] = obj[key];
  }

  return newObj;
}, {});
```

```js
const obj = {
  0: {
    'filter1': {
      'key1': {
        'email1': 'email1'
      }
    }
  },
  1: {
    'filter1': {
      'key12': {
        'email12': 'email12'
      }
    }
  },
  2: {
    'filter2': {
      'key2': {
        'email2': 'email2'
      }
    }
  }
};

const newObject = Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, key) => {
  if (!obj[key].filter1) {
    newObj[key] = obj[key];
  }

  return newObj;
}, {});

console.log(newObject);
```

Or as [@zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) said, using [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
const entries = Object.entries(obj).reduce((newObj, [key, val]) => {
  if (val.filter1) {
    return newObj;
  }

  return {
    ...newObj,
    [key]: val,
  }
}, {});
```

```js
const obj = {
  0: {
    'filter1': {
      'key1': {
        'email1': 'email1'
      }
    }
  },
  1: {
    'filter1': {
      'key12': {
        'email12': 'email12'
      }
    }
  },
  2: {
    'filter2': {
      'key2': {
        'email2': 'email2'
      }
    }
  }
};

const newObject = Object.entries(obj).reduce((newObj, [key, val]) => {
  if (val.filter1) {
    return newObj;
  }

  return {
    ...newObj,
    [key]: val,
  }
}, {});

console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: If you're using non-standard syntax anyway, why not use `Object.entries`?

Comment: @zerkms wouldn't it be longer though? `Object.entries(obj).reduce((newObj, entry) => {
  if (entry[1].filter1) {
    return newObj;
  }
  
  return {
    ...newObj,
    [entry[0]]: entry[1],
  }
}, {});`

Comment: But then you would have code without free variables. PS: `(newObj, [k, v])` perhaps: `Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => k.filter1 ? acc : { ...acc, [k]: v }, {});`

Answer (score 3):

Easy.

1. To remove an object you can use the `delete` API.
2. To check whether an object has a specific key you can use the
   `hasOwnProperty` API.

What you could do here is. First loop all of the keys in `obj` and then check whether its `value` (an object) has the `filter1` property. If they do then `delete` it away.

**Example:**

```js
const obj = {
    0: {
        'filter1': {
            'key1': {
                'email1': 'email1'
            }
        }
    },
    1: {
        'filter1': {
            'key12': {
                'email12': 'email12'
            }
        }
    },
    2: {
        'filter2': {
            'key2': {
                'email2': 'email2'
            }
        }
    }
};

for (var key in obj) {
    var objectInKey = obj[key];
    if (objectInKey.hasOwnProperty("filter1")) {
        delete obj[key]
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));

console.log(obj[0]); // <-- Should be undefined.
console.log(obj[2]); // <-- Should not be undefined as obj wasn't deleted.
```

Comment: I have a doubt.What will happen if you don't stringify `obj`. In that case it will still show the old object and its keys

Comment: @brk I have updated the test code to try accessing the deleted key to prove that they are indeed removed. Let me know if it clears your doubt.

Comment: If you use a loop `for ... in` then you have to check `if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue`.

Comment: @Paleo maybe I am missing something. My output is consistent with what OP was asking. I'm not sure why `!obj.hasOwnProperty(key) continue` is required.

Comment: @SamuelToh If you don't, iterations can occur in the loop for inherited members. In your code it is without consequence because `delete obj[key]` will do nothing with these wrong keys. But a future modification in the body of the loop could easily introduce a bug. It is a good practice to always protect `for ... in` with `hasOwnProperty`. Here is an example of code that adds an inherited key for all objects: `Object.prototype['abc'] = {'filter1': 123}`.

Comment: @Paleo ok I see what you mean here. Not quite applicable to OP's case as he is creating a pure `Object` unless the prototype for it has been touched. Unlikely but can be a potential fault if used on custom classes and it has key `filter1`, low chance but you never know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of key-value pairs, then use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to filter the data and translate it back into an object format.

```js
const obj = {
  0: { 'filter1': { 'key1':  { 'email1':  'email1'  } } },
  1: { 'filter1': { 'key12': { 'email12': 'email12' } } },
  2: { 'filter2': { 'key2':  { 'email2':  'email2'  } } }
};

console.log(Object.entries(obj).reduce((m, [k, v]) => (v.filter1 || (m[k] = v), m), {}));

// { "2": { "filter2": { "key2": { "email2": "email2" } } } }
```

**Further reading:**

- [`Object.entries` <sup>(mdn)</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [`Array#reduce` <sup>(mdn)</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 0):

To modify the object *in place* (rather than copying it, or creating arrays), I'd just use a simple loop and a delete:

```
let k = Object.keys(obj);
for (let i = 0; i < k.length ; i++ ) {
    if (obj[k[i]].hasOwnProperty('filter1')) delete obj[k[i]];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `filter`,

```
obj = obj.filter(o => o.filter1 == undefined);
```

See `filter` reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

**p.s. the `obj` in this example is a `var` not a `const`**, see snippet below

```js
var obj = [
  {
    'filter1': {
      'key1': {
        'email1': 'email1'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    'filter1': {
      'key12': {
        'email12': 'email12'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    'filter2': {
      'key2': {
        'email2': 'email2'
      }
    }
  }
];

console.log(obj); // initial obj
obj = obj.filter(o => o.filter1 == undefined);
console.log(obj); // element with `filter1` property is now deleted
```

Comment: OP does not have an array. It's also not obvious what you mean by "the obj in this example is a var not a const"

Comment: Setting the properties value to `undefined` doesn't actually remove the property.  For instance `Object.hasOwnProperty()` will still return `true`.  To completely remove it, use `delete`.